# How to use javascript or jquery to retrieve parameters from the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have a url that looks like: `http://www.my-site.com/#key=kj123asj`. I would like to retrieve `key` using javascript.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Seems everyone's pointing you to code which references the query string.

Assuming your parameters are in the fragment rather than the query string as in the example you gave, you can use the window.location.hash property to access them without parsing the entire URL yourself.

From there you can use code similar to what others have mentioned. A simple loop like this would work.

```
 var values = {},
  pairs = window.location.hash.substring(1).split('&'),
  pair;
 for (var i = 0, len = pairs.length; i < len; i++) {
  pair = pairs[i].split('=');
  values[pair[0]] = pair[1];
 }
 alert(values['key']);
```

Answer (score 2):

This JavaScript library can parse query strings in [standard format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) that is to say:

```
http://www.my-site.com/?key=kj123asj
```

The code to get `key` would be:

```
var qs = new Querystring();
var key = qs.get("key");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.extend({
  getUrlVars: function(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
  },
  getUrlVar: function(name){
    return $.getUrlVars()[name];
  }
});

// Get object of URL parameters
var allVars = $.getUrlVars();

// Getting URL var by its nam
var byName = $.getUrlVar('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var matches = location.href.match(/(key=)([a-z0-9]+)$/i);
```

The variable `matches` will be an array and matches[2] will contain the value of the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the entire URL from the variable `window.location.href`. After that, it's just a matter of searching the string for the `#` or `=` character and extracting the data after it. For example:

```
var s = window.location.href;
var i = s.indexOf('=');
var value = s.substr(i+1);
```

Of course, that only gets you the first value, and only works if you only have one value you want to extract. **However**, you could have that one value a JSON-encoded object, like so:

```
http://www.somewebsite.com/#data={key: 1293, foo: "bar"}
```

Then, do:

```
var map = JSON.parse(value);
```

You can now use normal JavaScript techniques to access the items:

```
var key = map['key'] // 1293
var foo = map['foo'] // "bar"
```

That should get you started, at least.

Answer (score -1):

Both answered here:
http://www.programmingfacts.com/2010/04/23/url-variables-javascriptjquery/